# Using numpy for hidden layer outpute given weights and biases

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, matrix

I have extracted the weights and biases for my hidden Tensorflow fully-connected layers (3 hidden-ReLU, 1 output-NoActivation) like so:

```
trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()

kernels_list = [trainable_variable for trainable_variable in trainable_variables if "DQN" in trainable_variable.name and "kernel" in trainable_variable.name]
biases_list = [trainable_variable for trainable_variable in trainable_variables if "DQN" in trainable_variable.name and "bias" in trainable_variable.name]

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

kval_list = [sess.run(kernels_list[i]) for i in range(len(kernels_list))]
bval_list = [sess.run(biases_list[i]) for i in range(len(biases_list))]
```

Given that the model is fully trained, I want to use these weights and biases to run a "numpy prediction". I have the input array which goes to the first hidden layer, then numpy uses those weights and biases to find the output from the first hidden layer etc. This is the code I am using to try and run these calculations:

```
x = state # state is my 1 dimensional input array

for i in range(0, len(kernels_list)):
    weights = kval_list[i]
    biases = bval_list[i]

    w = x.dot(weights)
    w += biases

    out = np.maximum(w, 0) # ReLU
    if i == len(kernels_list) - 1: # If output layer, no ReLU
        out = w

    x = out # Input to the next layer
```

However, when I compare the final `x` value (output layer) to the output layer using Tensorflow prediction, I get different values for each output node... Am I doing my matrix calculations wrong? The input layer has 1140 nodes, so `x.shape = (1140,)` initially and the first hidden layer has 600 nodes so `weights.shape = (1140, 600)` and `biases.shape = (600,)` in the first iteration.